# Benifit of chanting devi suktam individually?

Tags: scripture, shiva, yoga, durga, kali

In an article on hindupedia website which talks about strota chintamani it says to chant ya devi sarva bhuteshu smirti rupenaa" 108 times for 40 days to improve memory does same applies to things like buddhi,Chetna etc..

Comment: Yes ....................

Comment: @Rickross can u pls give more details like are there any rules like do I have to chant fix no. Of time everyday and can I chant more than one sloka a day also in my state temp. Is getting too low so can I chant without taking a bath

Comment: 108 times of a particular sloka/mantra like for Buddhi, Shakti etc. If you can't bath its not a big issue. You have to wash feet, hands, face and rinse your mouth. This is called Panchasuddhi and it makes one pure in the absence of bath.

Comment: @Rickross thnk u so much